# Prism V4 as an xbap

Tags: visual-studio-2010, prism, xbap, prism-4

I have tried most of the online tutorials I can find that tell you how to do an xbap application with Prism v4.

I keep running into blocks.  I am wondering if anyone has done this and if so, maybe they would be willing to share how they did it.

Again, this is Prism v4 running on Visual Studio 2010 (ultimate) as an WPF XBAP.

Comment: Could you add some more detail on the blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaccano,

While I don't have the XBAP for Prism v4, one of the devs on the team did convert Prism v2.1 to XBAP. There are some details at the CompositeWPF codeplex forums (thread 49824 - sorry can only post 1 link at SO) and more tech details about [migrating Prism v2.1 to XBAP here](http://blogs.southworks.net/matiasb/2009/03/11/using-cal-with-xbap-applications/).

Hope this helps,

Leon